# Normalization of an address table advice needed

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

I have a database with several tables

```
Student
Teacher
Parents
Staff
```

All need to have a reference to an address table

```
Address
    door number
    street
    town
    city
    postcode
```

How can I create a address table with little duplication of data? Is the only way to have separate tables for each?

Comment: you can use an  address table  in common between the others ..  but if the situation when different entities share the same address  then you can leave the address  in each entities

Comment: What are the primary keys of Student, Teacher, Parents & Staff tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a separate Address table with the following columns

```
address_id
door_number
street
town
city
state
country
postcode
```

Now in each of the tables - Student , Parent , Teacher , Staff - have an address_id column and create a foreign key to the address_id in the address table.

Assuming Student and Parent are already related, you can have the address just in the Parents table.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Rocky. This is were I'm at, but thought I am still going to have allot of duplication in the address table - for example the street name will be repeated over 200 times. My question is is there a better way.

Comment: You can make it completely normalized by having separate tables for street, town , city, state , country etc. That's good design , but downside is too many joins to get the required data. How much data do you anticipate , would you use it to just store with minimal reads ? or would you be accessing it on a regular basis ? if the requirement is to store and minimalistic read , then you can still go ahead with the completely normalized approach. However, if we want to search based on address , free text search and retrieve data , then normalized approach may not be the right choice

Comment: @MarkJames & Rocky There is nothing wrong with duplication per se. You are confusing duplication with redundancy & compression. And normalization would not suggest separate tables for street, town, etc and never involves introducing new columns like ids. (And if you introduce ids, the id for a value would appear everywhere the value does already, so you are not reducing repetitions.)